# XNA и использование spriteBatch без передачи по параметру

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

В классе `Game1` в любом `XNA` проекте объявляются методы `Game1`, `LoadContent`, `UnloadContent` и т.д.

Так же там объявляются переменные `GraphicsDeviceManager` и `SpriteBatch`. 
Для того, чтобы добавить возможность отрисовки через другой класс, необходимо в качестве одного из параметров метода передавать тот самый `SpriteBatch`.

Далее, в методе нужного нам класса мы обращаемся к `spriteBatch`:

```
public void Draw(SpriteBatch sprite)
{
   sprite.Begin()
   ...
}
```

Есть ли способ добиться возможности, который не требовал бы передачи этого аргумента в качестве параметра?

Answer (score 0):

Создать новый spriteBatch у объекта

```
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(game.GraphicsDevice);
```

где game, там объект класса игры наследуемого от Game, ну или можно стразу отправлять в инициализацию спрайта GraphicsDevice. У Каждого класса может быть свой spritebatch, да и каждый может рисоваться внутри другого

```
sb1.begin()
sb2.begin()
sb2.end()
sb1.end()
```